# Composing addition and division verbs over lists

Tags: j

If `data =: 3 1 4` and `frac =: % +/`, why does `% +/ data` result in `0.125` but `frac data` result in `0.375 0.125 0.5`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%+/ 3 1 4` is "sum, then find reciprocal of that sum", that is:

```
   +/ 3 1 4
8
   % 8       NB. same as 1%8
0.125
```

But if you define `frac =: %+/`, then `%+/` becomes a group of two verbs isolated from their arguments (aka tacit definition), that is, a [hook](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/hook):

```
   (%+/) 3 1 4
0.375 0.125 0.5
```

Which reads "sum, then divide original vector by that sum":

```
   +/ 3 1 4
8
   3 1 4 % 8
0.375 0.125 0.5
```

If you want `frac` to behave as in the first example, then you need to either use an explicit definition:

```
   frac =: 3 : '%+/y'
   frac 3 1 4
0.125
```

Or to compose `%` and `+/`, e.g. with [atop](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/at) conjunction or clever use of dyadic fork with [capped](https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/squarelfco) left branch:

```
   %@(+/) 3 1 4
0.125
   ([:%+/) 3 1 4
0.125
```